# How to convert ActiveRecord SQL query to array of hash without instanciating ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am developing a rails 4 app using ActiveRecord models for my db tables.
The main issue is that my model is quite complicated, and I would like to display a lot of information when I do an index of the main object.

For example, let's assume I have the following tables and columns:

```
Person:       name(string)
Address:      address(string), person_id(int)
EmailAddress: email(string), person_id(int)
Email:        spam (boolean), email_address_id(int)
```

and the relations:

```
person        has_many: :email_addresses
person        has_one:  :address
email_address has_many: :emails
```

Now I would like to display the following information

```
person.name
person.address.name
person.email_addresses.count
person.email_addresses.map do |email_address| 
  email_address.email.where(spam: false).count
end
```

The main issue is that I have a big amount of records, and I don't want to instantiate all of them (I have some memory issues because of that). Therefore, I was wondering how to do this kind of thing directly to get either an array of hashes or of arrays.

I managed to get the beginning using `pluck`:

```
Person.joins(:address).pluck('persons.name, addresses.address')
```

The problem begins with the count part.

Has someone already encountered such a situation? And is there a way to do this without writing the complete SQL query?

Comment: What's the database you are using ?

Comment: HI.
I have a postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `pluck` for complex queries, but you can always use [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) to fetch the columns you want. First you join all the tables you need. Note I joined `emails` table twice, the second one with the `spam: false` condition. Then you define your columns, directly from the table or `COUNT`'ed, in your `select` statement:

```
persons = Person.joins(:address, email_addresses: :emails).
   joins('INNER JOIN emails not_spammy_email_addresses ON emails.email_address_id = email_addresses.id AND emails.spam = 0').
   select('persons.name, addresses.address AS address_address,
           COUNT(email_addresses.id) AS email_addresses_count, 
           COUNT(not_spammy_email_addresses.id) AS not_spammy_email_addresses_count')
```

And then call your result's columns like this:

```
person = persons.first
person.name
person.address_address # note I'm not using *address* to prevent conflict with the model Adress 
person.email_addresses_count
person.not_spammy_email_addresses_count
```

I believe this is as far as you can get with `active_record` and a single query, but I'd love to see other approaches. For instance, if you use [`Arel`](https://github.com/rails/arel) this query would feel less *SQLish*.